# Can't change locale

Tags: 12.04, locale, utf-8

I've been struggling to make this software Anki work and it keeps saying:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 5, in <module>
    import aqt
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from aqt.qt import *
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 10, in <module>
    from anki.utils import isWin, isMac
  File "/usr/share/anki/anki/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise Exception("Anki requires a UTF-8 locale.")
Exception: Anki requires a UTF-8 locale.
```

I looked at some questions here and tried everything(I think) but can't change the locale setting somehow.

lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

My `locale` output:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

My `locale -a` output:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
```

Inside of /etc/default/locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Would you share the content of the file `/usr/share/anki/anki/__init__.py` with us, please? If it is long, you should consider uploading it to e.g. https://pastebin.org and posting the link here.

Comment: **en_US.UTF-8** ought to be the current locale according to what `/etc/default/locale` looks like, but the `locale` output indicates that some other config file unsets all locale settings. Do you have anything weird in e.g. `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`?

Comment: >Byte Commander Apparently pastebin.org is not working. And I don't know  such sites or service other than that. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Hiro, forget the file. It does not matter any more, as the problem was something else. But please read my comment below the answer , as that really confuses me...

Comment: And please also tell us the outputs of `grep "LANG" ~/.bashrc`, `grep "LANG" ~/.profile` and `grep "LANG" /etc/profile`. Usually none of those commands should show any output, but if one does for you, that could be the cause for the problem...

Comment: @ByteCommander the output of `grep "LANG" ~/.bashrc` is `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, because I tried to change it from .bashrc, which I remember didn't change a thing.

Comment: @ByteCommander output for neither `grep "LANG" ~/.profile` nor `grep "LANG" /etc/profile` is nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but your problem seems to be deeper than my knowledge of that part of Ubuntu... I fear you have to stay with your workaround and hope that maybe somebody else might be able to solve it later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by not having LANG variable set. Try running:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 anki
```

Comment: That should normally be set as environment variable (by default) and not manually before each program execution. However, if that solves the problem, @Hiro please show us the output of `env | grep "^LANG="`, which displays the `LANG` environment variable. It might be necessary to change it globally if it's wrong or missing there.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thank you. The output of env | grep "^LANG=" is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8
`

Comment: @adonis `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 anki` worked!

Comment: Now this seems really confusing to me, because overriding an environment variable with the exactly same value that is already set should not change anything... (???) @Hiro Did you run my command from a freshly opened terminal or have you already run any `LANG=...` commands inside that window before? Would you please check the output of `env | grep "^LANG="` from directly after a clean boot inside a fresh terminal window, if you don't mind? Because I feel really confused... Thank you.

Comment: I don't remember at this point if I ran the command in a certain terminal session, but I've been keeping  it in mind to change terminal to fresh to stay clear from confusion.

Comment: @ByteCommander `env | grep "^LANG="` is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8
`